# How can I get the value of an API result in Angular subscribe()?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I need to store some values in local storage after a successful login.

My API returns this

```
{
  "auth": {
    "name": "FooBar",
    "username: 'foobaz",
  },
  "token": "1234567890abcdefghijklmnop"
}
```

I've tried doing this within `login()` in `authentication.service.ts` but I can't figure it out. I've tried (among many other things) using `switchMap` multiple times inside `pipe()` with zero success.

#### authentication.service.ts

```js
login(credentials: { email: any, password: any }): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.post('https://mysite.test/api/login', credentials)
    .pipe(
      map((data: any) => data.token),
      switchMap(token => {
        return from(Preferences.set({ key: 'token', value: token }));
      }),
      tap(_ => {
        this.isAuthenticated.next(true);
      })
    )
}
```

So I thought I'd try it inside `.subscribe()` in `login.page.ts` but I keep receiving errors, like `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'res.auth.name')`.

Obviously that exists; I'm using `await`, plus I'm able to get `res.error.message` and read the message from the API when there's an error, so I'm really confused as to what I'm doing wrong?

I thought maybe I need to `map()` the result again but I just couldn't get that working. I can't find examples showing how to do what I want to do.

#### login.page.ts

```js
async login() {
  const loading = await this.loadingController.create();
  await loading.present();

  this.authService.login(this.myForm.value)
    .subscribe(
      async (res:any) => {

        // THIS IS WHAT I'M TRYING TO ACCOMPLISH
        await Preferences.set({ key: 'authName', value: res.auth.name });
        await Preferences.set({ key: 'authUsername', value: res.auth.username });

        await loading.dismiss();
        this.menu.enable(true);
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/tabs/home', { replaceUrl: true });
      },
      async (res) => {
        await loading.dismiss();
        const alert = await this.alertController.create({
          header: 'Login Failed',
          message: res.error.message,
          buttons: ['OK'],
        });
        await alert.present();
      }
    );
}
```

Comment: May I know what is the purpose and return value from `Preferences.set({ key: 'token', value: token })` in the `switchMap`?

Comment: The API requires a Bearer token for every endpoint except `/login`; this stores that token. If I `console.log(token)` in my API service it returns: `1234567890abcdefghijklmnop`

Comment: [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zs7jsz?file=src/app/authentication.service.ts). I believe that in `switchMap` you have returned an new Observable which have been overwritten the original Observable value. I would suggest you to perform the `Preferences.set` in `tap` operator. Checkout the Demo link I sent.

Comment: use this structure subscribe({next: (resp) => {...}, error: (err) => {...}})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is from the `switchMap` operator which you have created and returned another new Observable that overwrites the original Observable.

Would suggest performing the `Preferences.set` action in the `tap` operator to maintain the original Observable value.

```js
login(credentials: { email: any, password: any }): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.post('https://mysite.test/api/login', credentials)
    .pipe(
      tap((data: any) => {
        Preferences.set({ key: 'token', value: data.token });

        this.isAuthenticated.next(true);
      })
    )
}
```